# What kind of objects are both subobjects and quotients?

Tags: category-theory, exact-sequence

Fix an object $B$ in some category.

1. What does the existence of a diagram $A \rightarrowtail B
       \twoheadrightarrow A$ imply about $A$ and $B$?
2. What if $A \rightarrowtail B
       \twoheadrightarrow A$ is an exact sequence?

Comment: What motivation do you have for this question? Is there any example of a category where these are especially noteworthy conditions?

Comment: The question arose from thinking about short exact sequences. Viewing them as extensions, the exact sequence $A \rightarrowtail B \twoheadrightarrow A$ tells me that $B$ is an extension of $A$ by $A$, which seems strange. The first question is just more general.

Comment: It's not so strange to have an extension of $A$ by $A$. For example, $A \oplus A$ in any additive category...

Comment: Sure, but that's the "ideal case", where the sequence splits. Are the other examples?

Comment: Well, do you know any examples of sequences that don't split where the base and the fiber are _not_ the same?

Comment: I don't even know what a base and a fiber are..

Comment: I just mean the last and first terms of the short exact sequence. I'm just pointing out that before jumping to the idea that it should be "strange" for them to be the same, it might make sense to learn a few examples. Here's one: $0 \to \mathbb{Z}/2 \to \mathbb{Z}/4 \to \mathbb{Z}/2 \to 0$.